# What are the Drupal modules most used with CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, extension

I can see which CiviCRM Extensions are most used at [this link](http://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites).

I've just installed the Masquerade Drupal module, and want to see what else I might want to be using.

Is there an equivalent listing and ranking of the Drupal modules that are most used with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

I am quite curious about why you are asking this question. My advice would be to install only modules when you have functional need and those modules solve them for you.

It might be even that a module which is used often is completely useless in your context. Or that it breaks other needed functionality.

Having said that the masquerade module is very handy one. Same as views and webforms.

Comment: Thanks Jaap. I think there is definite and obvious value and time-savings in knowing the top Drupal modules (and Backdrop, WP, Joomla 'add-ons' as well) that folks using Civi find useful, just like we can see the top CiviCRM extensions at the extensions ranking at stats.civicrm.org .

Comment: So it is more a general knowledge question. Rather than that you want to install to most used modules lots of folks are using them. You can also ask this question on the Drupal Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

The CiviCRM stats collector doesn't collect that stat but besides webform_civicrm, it might not be too different from the list you'll see at https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module, which is sorted by most installed by default.

Rules and Organic Groups might be additional ones not high on that list because Civi bundles drupal modules that depend on those.

Comment: Agree with Demerit - Masquerade is not a module that would spring to my mind as 'good with civi' though we do have it on all our sites and use it LOTS.

Comment: Thanks Demerit and Pete. The Drupal module ranking is definitely handy. I'm hoping another clever person will point to a resource with a Civi unique Drupal module listing and rank, or way to calculate that. It seems like adding Drupal modules, Backdrop modules and WP and Joomla equivalents would be a really useful thing to have as well at stats CiviCRM.org .